How to pass struct[] array to solidity contract method using ethers?
This is the solidity code:
struct CallObject {
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 gas;
    address addr;
    bytes callvalue;
}

function userLand() public returns (uint256) {
        pusherLaminated.transfer(1 ether);

        CallObject[] memory pusherCallObjs = new CallObject[](2);
        pusherCallObjs[0] = CallObject({
            amount: 0,
            addr: address(mevTimeCompute),
            gas: 1000000,
            callvalue: abi.encodeWithSignature("solve()")
        });

        pusherCallObjs[1] = CallObject({amount: 33, addr: '0xE6C2607dc72082eF13a78fCbE09A384bD5fa0Fb4', gas: 10000000, callvalue: ""});

        return laminator.pushToProxy(abi.encode(pusherCallObjs), 1);
}

This is my approach. However, the resulting encoded object in typescript code is different from the value which I get from running the same code in Remix IDE.
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(['function solve()']);

const types = ['tuple(uint256 amount, address addr, uint256 gas, bytes callvalue)[]'];

const pusherCallObjs = [
    {
      amount: 0,
      addr: '0xfD056a94870b73fc774064Be41acF2cb18e5A25A',
      gas: 1000000,
      callvalue: iface.encodeFunctionData('solve', []),
    },
    {
      amount: 33,
      addr: '0xE6C2607dc72082eF13a78fCbE09A384bD5fa0Fb4',
      gas: 10000000,
      callvalue: '0x',
    },
  ];

const pusherCallObjsEncoded = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(types, [pusherCallObjs]);


You need to use the field types inside the tuple in the exact sequence as they're in the struct.
In the CallObject struct defined in your Solidity contract, gas of type uint256 is the second field and addr of type address is the third field, whereas inside the tuple of your TypeScript code, you're using address addr as the second field and uint256 gas as the third field.
So, the types array in your TypeScript should be defined as:
const types = ['tuple(uint256 amount, uint256 gas, address addr, bytes callvalue)[]'];

Then, the output of abi.encode(pusherCallObjs) of Solidity should be exactly same as pusherCallObjsEncoded of TypeScript, provided that the exact values of the arguments are passed.
So, with your exact inputs, it is:
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


Thank you so much. It worked. I have been debugging this for hours.

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
